# Google sheets значение в ячейке со временем не проходит проверку

Tags: google-spreadsheet, таблицы

Есть табличка с расписанием занятий, на отдельный лист собираются заявки прилетающие с google forms, затем посредствам скрипта данные с листа с заявками переносятся в лист с расписанием. В столбце B и С стоит время начала и конца занятия. На эти колонки настроена проверка данных из диапазона(выпадающий список) на листе TimeLib, когда время попадает из заявки оно не проходит проверку, а если ввести руками все хорошо.
Проверял на полное соответствие и там там данные в виде [Sat Dec 30 02:29:43 GMT-05:00 1899]

ссылка на табличку - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mKsKMpcijh81GF8R9APjMHb6iBvK_w8prWZao9MDZBA/edit?usp=sharing

код скрипта для копирования

```
function activeCheckBox () {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var userSheetToCopy = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Заявки');
  var userSheetFromCopy = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Расписание');
  var boxRange = userSheetToCopy.getRange(2, 11, (userSheetToCopy.getLastRow() - 1));
  

  boxRange.getValues().forEach((item, i) => {
    if (item == 'true') {
      if (userSheetToCopy.getRange(`A${i+2}`).getValue() != "") {
        
        let last_row = userSheetFromCopy.getRange(1, 1, userSheetFromCopy.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(String).length;
        let newArr = new Array();

        userSheetFromCopy.insertRowsAfter(last_row, 1);

        newArr.push(...userSheetToCopy.getRange(`B${i+2}:F${i+2}`).getValues());
        newArr.push(...userSheetToCopy.getRange(`J${i+2}`).getValues());
        newArr.push(...userSheetToCopy.getRange(`H${i+2}:I${i+2}`).getValues());

        userSheetFromCopy.getRange(`A${last_row + 1}:H${last_row + 1}`).setValues([newArr.flat()]);
        userSheetToCopy.getRange(`A${i+2}:J${i+2}`).setBackground('#97ff8a');
      }
    }
  });

  sorting();
  boxRange.setValue(false);

  spreadsheet.toast('Выбранные записи добавлены', 'Status', 3)
}
```

Comment: "когда время попадает из заявки оно не проходит проверку, а если ввести руками все хорошо"
Уточните, пожалуйста, в какие ячейки попадает время из формы - это столбцы C, D листа "Заявки"?
Если это так, то в каких ячейках время, полученное из формы, а в каких, введённое вручную.

Comment: @BorisBaublys "Уточните, пожалуйста, в какие ячейки попадает время из формы - это столбцы C, D листа "Заявки"?"     - Да всё верно, из формы время прилетает в  столбцы C, D листа "Заявки" . В листе "заявки" все время получено из формы и там проверки нет вообще. А в листе Расписание уже есть проверка это столбцы B, C. и вот там проверка не проходит когда перебрасываются значения из листа заявки. Но если вручную вбить в расписание время то все хорошо. пример строка. Пример строки 159 -164 - это значения переброшенные с заявки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените

```
newArr.push(...userSheetToCopy.getRange(`B${i+2}:F${i+2}`).getValues());
```

на

```
newArr.push(...userSheetToCopy.getRange(`B${i+2}:F${i+2}`).getDisplayValues());
```

и проверка будет проходить успешно.

Comment: Спасибо огромно, не знал о таких тонкостях)

Comment: Рад, что ваша проблема решена.